# How to to extract a specific line and column of a file in Linux?

Tags: file, command, cut, shellcode

Using command line tools, I need to extract the text "HTTP", (or whatever the protocol happens to be), right after the keyword "Detected protocol":

Partial file content :

```
Detected protocol:
       HTTP    1254
```

Complete file content:

```
    nDPI Memory statistics:
    nDPI Memory (once):      103.29 KB    
    Flow Memory (per flow):  1.91 KB      
    Actual Memory:           1.76 MB      
    Peak Memory:             1.76 MB      

Traffic statistics:
    Ethernet bytes:        1342          (includes ethernet CRC/IFC/trailer)
    Discarded bytes:       0            
    IP packets:            10            of 10 packets total
    IP bytes:              1102          (avg pkt size 110 bytes)           


Detected protocols:
    HTTP                 packets: 10            bytes: 1102          flows: 1            


Protocol statistics:
    Acceptable                    1102 bytes
```

Comment: I would suggest using multiline `sed` - see [here](http://superuser.com/a/634848/438726), or if you need more control, `awk`.

Comment: What would be the expected output of this sample input you just gave? Try to read [ask] to have a better experience here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you just want this to happen once, you can for example say:

```
awk 'matched {print $2; exit} /Detected protocol/ {matched=1}' file
```

Which returns:

```
1254
```

This checks is a line contains "Detected protocol". If so, it sets a flag that prompts a print in the next line. Then, it exits.

You can also set the field separator to `HTTP`:

```
awk -F"HTTP" 'f {print $2; exit} /Detected protocol/ {f=1}' file
```

Which returns the following for your updated input file:

```
                 packets: 10            bytes: 1102          flows: 1
```

Comment: the following error was occured :   awk: cmd. line:1: match {print $2; exit} /Detected protocol/ {match=1}  
awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ syntax error  
awk: cmd. line:1: match {print $2; exit} /Detected protocol/ {match=1}  
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                  ^ syntax error

Comment: @user3728748 this is my fault because I used `match` as a variable name, whereas it is a reserved word. Changed it to `awk 'matched {print $2; exit} /Detected protocol/ {matched=1}' file`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use

```
sed -n '/Dectected protocol/{n;p}' $file
```